# Android studio Paho Mqtt sample lib

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working with the PAHO Mqtt android library. Everything is working fine, until i got to the point where i wanted to make a message callback to receive message of a topic.

So i'm trying out this example https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.android.sample/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/android/sample/activity/MqttCallbackHandler.java

But it uses a library that i don't have imported:

```
import org.eclipse.paho.android.sample.R;
import org.eclipse.paho.android.sample.internal.Connections;
```

I have no idea on how to import them, this is the official guide on how to import the libraries but they never show anything about a 'sample' lib.

https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/

They only use Client and Android lib

Any help is appreciated